# Why doesn't ls combined with awk show exact sizes?

Tags: command-line, files, disk-usage, awk, ls

I am trying to find the size of the files on my hard drive in exact bytes, but whenever the size gets too big the number turns all weird (like 1.98329e+12). Can I stop it from doing this or convert this into exact bytes?

The command is:

```
ls -lR | grep -v '^d' | awk '{total += $5} END {print "Total:", total}'
```

Picture of exact bytes:

[image: img]

Picture of weird number:

[image: img]

- The cut-off point before it stops showing exact bytes seems to be around 500gb
- The command `du -sb` properly shows exact bytes no matter how big the directory is.
- I have tried Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 64bit (Japanese and English) and Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64bit (Japanese)
- My drives are `ntfs` so I tried formatting one as ext4 and copying my files over. The results are same as ntfs.

Comment: Use du command for size. ls is unfit for that purpose

Comment: I would prefer ls because directory sizes vary while file sizes are constant

Comment: A lot of people prefer ls because it seems simple, but because its simple it has a lot of issues and generally is only good for listing files. Tasks such yours require different tools, and recursive behavior. Also, can you explain what do you mean by file and directory sizes being different and constant ? Unless you move files around on the drive, directory should remain the same too.

Comment: You blame `ls` but clearly the problem is with the way **awk** displays the final result. The answer by @kos shows how to correct this.

Comment: @alexis  There's a lot more going on behind the scenes.`AWK` merely operates on the text. `ls` on the other hand is the one giving output to `awk`  , and that data can be incorrect in a lot of ways.  For example `ls -l /dev/sda` will not show you the disk usage of sda as many people think.  `ls` should be used for only listing stuff, nothing more. OP's purpose is to find total disk size of all the files.

Comment: @パンツ I've made some edits to my answer. Please see the final result.

Comment: @alexis  see this also http://superuser.com/a/94220/418028

Comment: @Serg, no argument there. "Total disk size" is a strange goal anyway-- what is meant to be measured? Whatever it is, there's a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that MAWK (the AWK variant installed on Ubuntu) by default prints integers bigger than `2147483647` (2<sup>31</sup>-1) in scientific notation:

```
% awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
% printf '2147483647\n' | awk '{x += $1; print x}'
2147483647
% printf '2147483648\n' | awk '{x += $1; print x}'
2.14748e+09
```

You could use `printf` with a format specifer instead of `print`*:

```bsh
printf '2147483648\n' | awk '{x += $1; printf "%.0f\n", x}'
```

```
% printf '2147483648\n' | awk '{x += $1; printf "%.0f\n", x}'
2147483648
```

In your case:

```bsh
ls -lR | grep -v '^d' | awk '{total += $5} END {printf "Total:%.0f\n", total}'
```

```bsh
ls -lR |
    grep -v '^d' |
    awk '
        {
            total += $5
        }
        END {
            printf "Total:%.0f\n", total
        }
    '
```

That will force AWK to print `total` in decimal notation instead of in scientific notation.

However, on another note, [you should never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

A more sensitive way to do that would be using `find` + `stat`:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%s' {} + | awk '{total += $1} END {printf "Total:%.0f\n", total}'
```

```bsh
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%s' {} + |
    awk '
        {
            total += $1
        }
        END {
            printf "Total:%.0f\n", total
        }
    '
```

---

*`%.0f` is a trick to make `printf` print numbers bigger than `2147483647` (2<sup>31</sup>-1), which when using `%d` as the format specifier would always print as `2147483647`. The limit of `%.0f` is that one will start losing precision after `9007199254740992` (2<sup>53</sup>), if that's ever a concern (thanks to Rotsor for the useful information).

Comment: Ok but i would use du  with -b flag instead of stat

Comment: @Serg Why exactly? In case of filenames containing newlines it's subject to the same pitfall as `ls -l | grep -v '^d'`, and will print two lines instead of one. One could use `du -0`, but then one should also set AWK to read NUL-terminated strings. I don't see a reason to use `du` in place of `stat` in this case.

Comment: Aside form having `-b` flag to produce size in bytes as OP wants, there is `-c` flag, which produces grand total. So there's no need for `awk` that way. In addition, OP is not concerned with printing the file , so there's no need to be concerned about newlines

Comment: I've posted that as an answer

Comment: @Serg It doesn't matter, `du` will print the filename regardless, and that will mess up the AWK command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15671308/

Comment: The first number you lose precision at is going to be `9007199254740993` (`2^53 + 1`) (8 PiB). This is because double-precision floating-point numbers have 52-bit mantissa, resulting in 53-bit effective precision.

Comment: ...but you lose precision long before that by ignoring directories' contribution to the total size. :)

Comment: @Rotsor Thanks, that seems to be accurate. That's what I thought initially but I was unsure whether MAWK would have done some trick to support an even higher precision. Apparently not, `9007199254740993` itself is represented as `9007199254740992`.

Comment: @Rotsor That's true as well. You should tell OP about that :)

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: `ls` and `awk` are unnecessary for your purpose. Use `du -cb` or `du -bs` on the directory that you want to analyse.

Your purpose is to

1. Find all files
2. find their size (in bytes)
3. produce grand total for all of them

All these actions can be performed by `du`.

```
$ du -bs $HOME 2>/dev/null                                                                 
76709521942 /home/xieerqi
```

It's worth noticing that `du` has two "modes" - it can either show how much file is in size OR how much actual disk space it takes up (the real , physical real-estate). Since you are interested in total size of all files, you want the apparent file size. `-b` flag gives exactly that  ( `-b` is alias for `--apparent-size --block-size=1` ).

Perhaps even more concise and appropriate solution would be to use `du -bc` directly on the directory you want. For instance, my home directory is about 76 GB in size

```
$ du -bc $HOME 2> /dev/null  | tail -1                    
76694582570 total
```

For some reason you worry about difference in folder size and file size.You said in the comments:

> I would prefer ls because directory sizes vary while file sizes are
>   constant

`du` is recursive, and sums up the file sizes. Also, a directory does have a static size of 4096 bytes ( 4k ) , but with `du` it will be included in the result of `du -bs directory_name` . Consider this:

```
$ du -b suse/openSUSE-Leap-42.1-DVD-x86_64.iso                                             
4648337408  suse/openSUSE-Leap-42.1-DVD-x86_64.iso

$ du -b suse/                                                                              
4648341504  suse/

$ bc <<< "4648337408+4096" 
4648341504

$ mkdir suse/another_dir  

$ du -b suse/another_dir                                                                   
4096    suse/another_dir

$ du -bs suse/                                                                             
4648345600  suse/
```

Comment: @kos `-s` produces total for each argument, so if arguments were directories, it would produce summary for all of them and output in for `size dir_name` , so last line would be whatever last argument was. `-c` actually produces the sum of sizes of all the arguments given and gives last line as grand total :)

Comment: I meant a literal `du -s .`, not `find .  -type f -exec du -s {}   \+  2> /dev/null  | awk 'END{print $0}'` (and by the way since they want bytes I'll correct that to `du -bs .`).

Comment: @kos I've added that to my answer :)

Comment: I was just re-reading and tested again, sorry, I didn't know `-b` implied `--apparent-size`. Removed that comment (and the imprecise first comment).

Comment: I always use `du -cks` which is useful, easy to remember, and funny.

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood, `awk` does all calculations using double-precision floating point numbers.  By default it prints them using [`printf(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/printf.3) format specifier `%.6g`, which means that if the number is more than six digits wide it will switch over to [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), which is what you saw.  You can work around this by setting the variable `OFMT`:

```
ls -lR |
    awk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%d" }  
         /^-/  { total += $5 } 
         END   { print "Total:", total }'
```

But there is an upper limit, beyond which it *can't* give you an exact number of bytes; it will start rounding off the low bits of the sum.  500 gigabytes = 500 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 536870912000 ≈ 2<sup>39</sup>.  With the usual IEEE floating point, this is safely below that limit (which is *roughly* 2<sup>52</sup>).  However, it is large enough that I personally would feel better using a programming language that had proper "bignums" (unlimited-size integers).  For instance, Python:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

space = 0L  # L means "long" - not necessary in Python 3
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for f in files:
        space += os.lstat(os.path.join(subdir, f)).st_size

sys.stdout.write("Total: {:d}\n".format(space))
```

This is also completely immune to problems with files with unusual characters in their names.  And it counts space consumed by hidden files.

This computes the *number of bytes visible in each file*, which is the same as what `ls -l` prints. If you want *number of bytes actually occupied on disk* instead (what `du` prints), replace `.st_size` with `.st_blocks * 512`.  (Yes, the multiplier is always 512, even if `st_blksize` is a different number.)

Comment: You've mixed up   the order. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) .  Order should be `dirpath, dirnames, filenames`

Comment: @Serg I just fixed that :)

Comment: I've had a small issue with your code, so had to ask a question. See my post http://stackoverflow.com/q/36484470/3701431

Comment: +1 but on a side note the upper limit before the switch to a scientific notation is not exact, neither in GAWK nor in MAWK (the default AWK variant on Ubuntu, where the upper limit is higher, 2^32, i.e. the usual maximum size of an `int`, the maximum number representable being 2147483647). GAWK seems to have an even bigger upper limit, though I didn't test it nor I went through the documentation / source code (yet).

Comment: @Serg Gah, I should have thought of that - answer is now corrected. The _right_ fix for the symlink problem you found is to use `os.lstat` instead of `os.stat`, because in this context, you _do_ want to count the size of the symlinks themselves and you _don't_ want to count the size of what they point to (if the pointee is inside the tree it should be counted only once; if it's outside it shouldn't be counted at all).

Answer (score 3):

What you see here is a way to display large numbers. For example:

```
1.23e+3 = 1.23*10^3 = 1230
```

As far as I know, you cannot turn this off, but as you wrote in your question, `du` does behave differently, so I would recommend to use this. Otherwise, you would have to convert the numbers.